# Get List of Installed Applications Windows Mobile (C# Managed)

Tags: windows-mobile, compact-framework

I need to get List of Installed Application on Windows Mobile using C#.

After that, I want to have capability to get notifications when installed application starts, ends etc.

Answer (score 1):

When an app is installed by wceload, which is the typical install route, then an entry gets added in the registry here:

```
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Apps]
```

So you can enumerate keys and values here to determine what is installed and where in the file system it resides.

Getting a notification when an app starts is much, much more difficult because the system simply isn't designed to tell you that.  The route I'd likely go is to use the [Toolhelp API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa450774.aspx) to periodically enumerate the running processes to determine what is new or gone.  Microsoft does not provide a Toolhelp implementation, but it's fairly easy to P/Invoke, or you can use something like the SDF, which already has it done.

Answer (score 0):

I got the answer from http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/windowsmobiledev/thread/eb43dce3-8b90-4c15-88bf-3791b4a97a58.

Answer (score 0):

For your second question, instead of GetCurrentProcess(), use GetProcess(string) or GetProcessById(int)

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x8b2hzk8.aspx

To get the process ID, you can p/invoke the ToolHelpAPI. Here's an article explaining that process:
http://alexmogurenko.com/blog/programming/windows-cemobile-get-process-list-c/

-PaulH