# .NET Compact Framework, enumerate windows (windows mobile)

Tags: c#, windows-mobile, compact-framework

is there any way to enumerate windows in .net compact framework, than using PInvoke `EnumWindows`?

Comment: does this make any sense [Get List of Installed Applications Windows Mobile (C# Managed)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3869921/get-list-of-installed-applications-windows-mobile-c-managed)? I mean I am not a windows mobile guy but you can't seem to get help. Your quetion is the first link when I type "how to enumarate windows in .net compact" in google.

Comment: @BurnAfterReading: No, it doesn't make any sense in this context. The question deals with windows of currently running processes, not what programs are installed.

Comment: @Johann Gerell thanks for the explanation Mr.Gerell

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> is there any way to enumerate windows in .net compact framework, than using PInvoke EnumWindows?

Nope. No shortcuts. Either do the P/Invoke enumeration yourself or use a library that does it for you.